# XPath to determine if predecessors or ancestors have content, regardless of level

Tags: c#, dom, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm working on a process that reads a news article in raw HTML. The news articles come from a variety of sources and therefore are not consistent.

The goal is to locate the first image in the article, and if there is no content prior to it, strip the image out.

Our data is inconsistent (as it comes from a variety of sources), for instance...

No content before first image examples:

```
A: <p><a href="..."><img src="..." /></a></p><p>content</p>

B: <img src="..." /><p>content</p>

C: <div><p><img src="..." /></p></div><div><p>content</p></div>

D: <div><img src="..." /></div><div><p>content</p></div>

E: <div><p><a href="..."><img src="..." /></a>content</p></div>
```

In short, the first image and the first content could be at any level of the document. Therefore, the requirement is this:

1. Find the first image in the document
2. Look at all predecessors and ancestors, regardless of depth, and determine if they contain content. (Let's ignore iframes/embedded items for the purposes of this exercise.)
3. If they are all empty, remove the image and all containers for it if they don't contain any other content.

I have a semi-functional example, but don't believe I have the XPath query down.

Here is my code so far - which uses [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and is not yet optimized (duplicate code because I'm testing out various methods to accomplish my goal). What I'm unsure about, and the purpose of my question, is to confirm the proper usage of:

```
(//img)[1]/preceding::*|(//img)[1]/ancestor::*/@id
```

and

```
(//img)[1]/preceding::*[not(text())]|(//img)[1]/ancestor::*[not(text())]/@id"
```

to locate all predecessors and ancestors for an image, then all predecessors and ancestors for an image with no content respectively.

```
            HtmlNode firstImageInArticle = rawContentModifier.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("(//img)[1]");
            if (firstImageInArticle == null) { // there are no images in this article - return HTML as is.
                return html;
            }

            // count all nodes and all empty nodes preceding the first image in the article
            HtmlNodeCollection allNodesPrecedingFirstImage = rawContentModifier.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("(//img)[1]/preceding::*|(//img)[1]/ancestor::*/@id");
            HtmlNodeCollection allEmptyNodesPrecedingFirstImage = rawContentModifier.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("(//img)[1]/preceding::*[not(text())]|(//img)[1]/ancestor::*[not(text())]/@id");

            // if there are no nodes preceding the first image, we have no content prior to the image and therefore should delete it
            if (allEmptyNodesPrecedingFirstImage == null || allNodesPrecedingFirstImage == null) {
                HtmlNode nodeToDelete = rawContentModifier.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(firstImageInArticle.XPath);

                // keep moving up the chain until we find the topmost parent that doesn't have any other children
                while (nodeToDelete.ParentNode.ChildNodes.Count == 1)
                {
                    nodeToDelete = nodeToDelete.ParentNode;
                }
                nodeToDelete.Remove();

                html = rawContentModifier.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
                return html;                    
            }

            // if the number of empty nodes preceding the first image is equal to all nodes preceding the first image...
            // then we know that we basically have no content prior to the image and therefore can delete the first image
            if (allNodesPrecedingFirstImage.Count == allEmptyNodesPrecedingFirstImage.Count) {
                HtmlNode nodeToDelete = rawContentModifier.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(firstImageInArticle.XPath);

                // keep moving up the chain until we find the topmost parent that doesn't have any other children
                while (nodeToDelete.ParentNode.ChildNodes.Count == 1)
                {
                    nodeToDelete = nodeToDelete.ParentNode;
                }
                nodeToDelete.Remove();

                html = rawContentModifier.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
                return html;
            }
```

Edited to add example E, which is failing with my code as the P tag contains content after the image, but is not self contained.